# How to generate array-list of all combinations of a table in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I want to make automated measurements varying several parameters.
There is a table with variable row/column-number containing parameter values, e.g.:

```
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 b3 c3
```

Is there an easy was for generating list of Arrays containing all combinations in column direction like that:

```
a1 a2 a3
b1 a2 a3
c1 a2 a3
a1 b2 a3
b1 b2 a3
...
c1 c2 c3
```

3x3 Table should result in 27 combinations (3!).

The algorthm should be if possible in C/C++, STL/Qt would be also great.

Thank you for any hint!

P.S.:
It looks easy, but I have sat on this problem since 2 hours already! :-(

Comment: How far have you gotten in those 2 hours? Post some of your code (along with what worked and what didn't) and you will be more likely to get helpful responses.

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: He's making "automated measurements". I doubt it's homework or an interview question (but it's still possible).

Comment: 3! is not 27 it's 6. 3^3 is 27, and that's how many different combinations there are. There will be columns^rows different combinations and generating them is nearly trivial and does not require recursion.

Comment: I can create one that's probably at least 10 times faster than any of the ones given as answers so far.

Comment: @Omnifarious 1) Nothing requires (implicit) recursion; 2) Perhaps post it as an answer then?

Comment: @Omnifarious: Oh, thank you. How embarrassing. Is there any easier way? Something like double-loop? There are many questions on that problem at SO, but I've found only answers for R, SQL, not C/C++

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz You could do it with loops but you would have to nest them. In your example you would need three nested loops but with a larger number of rows you would need many more loops. My answer works for any number of rows or columns but if you have a small number of rows, it may be faster just to do a few loops.

Comment: @dauphic, @ the.malkolm: No, it is not. It is only a desperate attempt at 2am to get the delivery done for 9am :-)

Comment: I'll give you a solution to use that will work as long as you can guarantee that `columns^rows <= ULLONG_MAX`. It can be modified to work otherwise, but it gets a lot more complex (though still tons faster).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
int selection[rows]; // Stores which item is selected for each row

void func(int row_num) {
    if (row_num == rows) { // If we've selected for all the rows
        // Do your thing with selection[]
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) { // For each possible selection you can make row_num
        selection[row_num] = i; // Choose it
        func(row_num + 1); // Recurse over all possible combinations for the remaining rows
    } 
}

func(0); // Goes over all possibilities
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess, I should take your proposal :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the promised code. It requires C++11 to run, but it's not that hard to modify it to work with C++98.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>

typedef ::std::vector< ::std::string > rowvec_t;
typedef ::std::vector< rowvec_t > combovec_t;

constexpr unsigned long long
int_log(unsigned long long v, unsigned long long base)
{
   return (v <= base) ? 0 : (1u + int_log(v / base, base));
}

constexpr unsigned long long
int_pow(unsigned long long base, unsigned long long exp)
{
   return (exp < 1) ? 1 :
      ((exp & 1) ? (base * int_pow(base, exp - 1)) :
       int_pow(base * base, exp / 2));
}

combovec_t count_em_all(const combovec_t &input)
{
   const combovec_t::size_type rows = input.size();
   if (rows <= 0) {
      return combovec_t();
   }
   const rowvec_t::size_type cols = input[0].size();
   if (int_log(::std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max(), cols) < rows) {
      throw ::std::overflow_error("Too many rows and columns");
   }
   const unsigned long long total_ct = int_pow(cols, rows);
   combovec_t result;
   for (unsigned long long ct = 0; ct < total_ct; ++ct) {
      rowvec_t cur_row;
      unsigned long long alldigits = ct;
      for (unsigned outcol = 0; outcol < rows; ++outcol) {
         const unsigned long long digit = alldigits % cols;
         alldigits /= cols;
         cur_row.emplace_back(input[outcol][digit]);
      }
      result.emplace_back(::std::move(cur_row));
   }
   return ::std::move(result);
}

const combovec_t test = { { "a1", "b1", "c1" },
                          { "a2", "b2", "c2" },
                          { "a3", "b3", "c3" } };

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   combovec_t result = count_em_all(test);
   for (rowvec_t &row: result) {
      for (::std::string &col: row) {
         ::std::cout << col << ' ';
      }
      ::std::cout << '\n';
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This basically treats the problem as the problem of counting in base b (where b is the number of columns). Each output is an n (where n is the number of rows in the input) digit number where each digit is one of the columns.

Comment: +1 simply for the effort but do you have any "proof" of speed increase?

Comment: @quasiverse: Well, I can't give you proof because the other solutions do not come with enough code to actually function. I could modify it to use the data structure that another answer assumes and then wrap up the other solution in enough code to be able to test.

Comment: whoever gave -1, should please comment why! @Omnifarious doesn't loo that easy. 64 LOCs - requires average programmer a day to implement :-)

Comment: @quasiverse: The test I did shows that it, in fact, my solution is slower than the recursive solution. This kind of surprises me.

Comment: @quasiverse: More testing shows that if I enable profile-guided optimizations they become almost identical in speed. Interesting. They both benefit, but yours only benefits slightly, and mine benefits a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

@quasiverse: Thank you, looks like recursive function is the most elegant way.

OK, my version looks ugly but works now. I post it only because of boring comments.

```
    // array containing column-indexes, all set to column 0
    QByteArray idxs(rows,0); 
    // array containing max indexes for column
    QByteArray endIdxs(rows,cols-1);
    //repeat, untill all indexes in idxs are max - all combinations done.
    do{            
        _varParamTestList.append( idxs );
        for( int r=0; r< rows; ++r )
        {
            int v = idxs[r];
            v++;
            if ( v >= cols )
            {
                idxs[r]=0;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                idxs[r] = v;
                _varParamTestList.append( idxs );
                break;
            }
            _varParamTestList.append( idxs );
        }
    }while ( idxs != endIdxs );
```