# Displaying Matrix elements in Strange Order

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was not really sure what this order of printing is called hence called it strange.

Consider the following sample example:

```
1 3 5
2 6 7
```

Expected output:

```
1,2
1,6
1,7
3,2
3,6
3,7
5,2
5,6
5,7
```

Or this example:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

output:

```
1,4,7
1,4,8
1,4,9
1,5,7
1,5,8
1,5,9 
... and so on.
```

I have analyzed that the number of possible combinations will be `rows^columns` for any given matrix.Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void printAllPossibleCombinations(int** a, int h, int n, string prefix)
{
    if (h == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << prefix << a[0][i] << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            string recursiveString = prefix;
            recursiveString.append(to_string(a[h][i]));
            recursiveString.append(1, ',');
            printAllPossibleCombinations(a, h-1, n, recursiveString);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int **a;
    int m,n,k;

    cout<<"Enter number of rows: ";
    cin>>m;
    a = new int*[m];

    cout<<endl<<"Enter number of columns: ";
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        a[i] = new int [n];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter a[" << i << "][" << j<< "] = ";
            cin>>a[i][j];
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    printAllPossibleCombinations(a, m-1, n, "");

    return 0;
}
```

Is there an easy and more optimized way of doing it? Please suggest.

Thank You

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do.  In particular, what do you want to print when there are more than 2 rows?

Comment: I will add an example of 3*3 matrix too!!

Comment: @j_random_hacker I hope its clear now.I edited my question.

Comment: So, you want the Cartesian product, in a particular order?

Comment: @Yakk Not exactly!! I edited my question for 3*3 matrix also. Now it will me more clear.

Comment: Still a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_product).

Comment: @beaker My method is too big and may be there is a more elegant way of doing this. If you can give me any suggestions for the same.

Comment: In what way is what you want different than a Cartesian product (with the elements in a particular order) of the rows?

Comment: Here are a couple of approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507682/how-to-generate-array-list-of-all-combinations-of-a-table-in-c-c. If anyone knows of a canonical duplicate, please post. There has to be one somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, there are `rows^columns` things to physically print out in the algorithm so you can't do better than an `O(rows^columns)` algorithm and your algorithm is as optimal as you'll get.